# Safe to delete /private/var/tmp/*?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, storage

In this folder, there are 14GB of archives with names such as WiFiDiagnostics follow by a date. Is it safe to delete these archives? A reboot did not remove them.

Comment: Similar to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288227/can-i-delete-the-logs-in-the-private-tmp-folder

Comment: I use a freeware program called Onyx to clean my Mac of such things. It clears caches and runs all of Apple's maintenance scripts which will delete expired log entries. I find that program a lot simpler than searching out large files and hoping that deleting them is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WiFiDiagnostics*` sounds like something you can delete without impact. There are other things in `/private/var/tmp` which probably shouldn't get deleted (e.g. `filesystemui.socket`) so `rm *` is not advisable.